# toggle Onclick of button arrow up and arrow down icon change in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

i want to toggle the mat icon on-click arrow it should **UP** and on-click again the same mat icon the arrow should **Down**.

For Referrence stack Blitz:- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnvhnn-jtlqod?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html

What i am exactly looking is if we click **Monster** arrow, this arrow only needs to toggle up and down, and if we click **Roach** arrow, this arrow only needs to toggle up and down so please help us how can we achieve this in angular?

Please check the below code for referrence:-

```
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-evenly;">
    <div *ngFor="let value of cricketList">
        <p (click)='clickOntab(tab)' >{{value.player}}</p>
    <button class="staticIcon"   (onShown)="onPopoverShown()" mat-icon-button>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="!showLess" (click)="showResult(hub)">expand_more</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngIf="showLess" (click)="hideResult(hub)">expand_less</mat-icon>
     </button>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**sample data:-**

```
 cricketList = [
    {
      player: "Monster",
      category: "basket"
    },
    {
      player: "Roach",
      category: "cricket"
    },
    {
      player: "Messi",
      category: "football"
    },
    {
      player: "Ms",
      category: "carrom"
    },
    {
      player: "Fedral",
      category: "tennis"
    }
        
  ];
```

**toggle method**

```
showResult(){
   
    let showLess = true;
  }

  hideResult() {
    let showLess = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add param bool to each item in array and change that one

```
cricketList = [
    {
      player: "Monster",
      category: "basket",
      showLess:false
    },
    {
      player: "Roach",
      category: "cricket",
      showLess:false
    },
    {
      player: "Messi",
      category: "football",
      showLess:false
    },
    {
      player: "Ms",
      category: "carrom",
      showLess:false
    },
    {
      player: "Fedral",
      category: "tennis",
      showLess:false
    }
        
  ];
```

in html change this

```
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-evenly;">
    <div *ngFor="let value of cricketList">
        <p (click)='clickOntab(tab)'>{{value.player}}</p>
        <button class="staticIcon"   (onShown)="onPopoverShown()" mat-icon-button>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="!value.showLess" (click)="showResult(value)">expand_more</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngIf="value.showLess" (click)="hideResult(value)">expand_less</mat-icon>
     </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

in component

```
showResult(param){
   
    param.showLess = true;
  }
  hideResult(param) {
    param.showLess = false;
  }
```

Comment: thanks. and which popover is best to use in angular do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

In expansion-overview-example.html :-

```
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: space-evenly;">
    <div *ngFor="let value of cricketList; let i = index">
        <p (click)='clickOntab(tab)' >{{value.player}}</p>
    <button class="staticIcon" (onShown)="onPopoverShown()" (click)="toggleResult(i)" mat-icon-button>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="value.showMore">expand_more</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="!value.showMore">expand_less</mat-icon>
     </button>  
    </div>
</div>
```

In expansion-overview-example.ts :-

```
   cricketList = [
    {
      player: "Monster",
      category: "basket",
      showMore: false
    },
    {
      player: "Roach",
      category: "cricket",
      showMore: false
    },
    {
      player: "Messi",
      category: "football",
      showMore: false
    },
    {
      player: "Ms",
      category: "carrom",
      showMore: false
    },
    {
      player: "Fedral",
      category: "tennis",
      showMore: false
    }
        
  ];

  toggleResult(i) {
    this.cricketList[i].showMore = !this.cricketList[i].showMore;
  }
```

Happy Coding!!